# OrientDB Backup structure and class value

Tags: backup, orientdb

I have a big (?) db (more than 3G). I would like to copy to another server only the db structure and the data for one class.
Is there an easy way to do it other than backup + restore of the whole db and than empty all the classes that I don't need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refer to this http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Export.html

You can even export only classes you need.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'm sorry that I didn't properly RTFM before posting.